# Angular & Node.js: Unable to Clear Local Storage, Session Storage, and auth_token While Logging Out

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, mongodb, git

I am currently developing a web application using Angular for the frontend and Node.js for the backend. My application utilizes local storage, session storage, and an auth_token for authentication and session management. However, I am encountering a significant issue: upon logging out, neither the local storage nor the session storage keys and values are being cleared. Additionally, the auth_token remains intact.

The problem is even more confounding because when I attempt to log out, it appears as though the system is logging me back in. Specifically, when I refresh the page, a message displays: "Received username from server."

Furthermore, when I trigger the logout function, I get an HTTP 404 error with the message "Logout failed HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', url: 'http://localhost:4200/api/logout', ok: false}."

What I Tried & What I Was Expecting:
I have tried invoking methods to clear local storage and session storage using localStorage.clear() and sessionStorage.clear(). I also attempted to nullify the auth_token. My expectation was that these actions would invalidate the current session and enable a complete logout.

For the HTTP 404 issue, I checked my API endpoint and ensured it is reachable and correctly defined. I expected that hitting the API endpoint should handle the logout operation seamlessly and give me a 200 OK status instead of a 404.

The problem lies in both the persistence of local data and the failure of the logout API call. I expected that upon logout, all session-related data would be cleared and that I would be able to log out without encountering any errors.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.